# Shifting elements of an array to the right

Tags: java, arrays

I am aware that there are solutions for shifting arrays out there. However no solution works for me. The code should achieve the following:

The method `shift(int[] array, int places)` takes in an `array`, shifts the elements `places` - times to the right **and** replaces the "leftover" elements with "0".

So far I have:

```java
public static int[] shiftWithDrop(int[] array, int places) {
            
    if (places == 0 || array == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for (int i = array.length-places-1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        array[i+places] = array[i];
        array[i] = 0;
    }               
    return array;
}
```

This code does only somehow work, but it does not return the desired result. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you return `null` when `places` is 0? That's very unintuitive behavior

Comment: And you really need to show a case where it doesn't return the desired result, see also [mre]

Comment: Don't modify the input array, create a local variable instead and use that to move values and to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in this code:

1. It returns `null` when `places == 0` -- without shift, the original array needs to be returned
2. In the given loop implementation the major part of the array may be skipped and instead of replacing the first `places` elements with 0, actually a few elements in the beginning of the array are set to 0.

Also it is better to change the signature of the method to set places before the vararg `array.`

So to address these issues, the following solution is offered:

```java
public static int[] shiftWithDrop(int places, int ... array) {
    if(array == null || places <= 0) {
        return array;
    }
    for (int i = array.length; i-- > 0;) {
        array[i] = i  < places ? 0 : array[i - places];
    }
    
    return array;
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shiftWithDrop(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shiftWithDrop(2, new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5})));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shiftWithDrop(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shiftWithDrop(7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you verry much! Now I see the flaws my code had. Also your loop solution is much more efficient

Comment: Since I am fairly new to Java, would you mind explaining the for loop without the use of the tenary operator?

Comment: What do you mean?  The loop is run in reverse mode (from last element to the first), `i` decreasing from `n - 1` to `0`, and the ternary operator checks when 0 should be supplied instead of the value shifted by `places`.  So, for `n = 5` and `places = 3`, `arr[4] = arr[1], arr[3] = arr[0]`; `arr[2]` and further set to `0` (2, 1, 0 < 3)